How do I prove this claim? "a system is LTI if and only if it's a convolution system"
I haven't heard about the term "convolution system" and the definition we were given in the question is that it's a system that the connection between input and output is the following:
$$y\left(t\right)=\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\left(\tau\right)h\left(t-\tau\right)d\tau=\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\left(t-\tau\right)h\left(\tau\right)d\tau$$
when \$h(t)\$ is the impulse response for \$x(t)=\delta(t)\$.
I need to show this holds for both ways, so given LTI -> convolution system and the other way around.
I tried to play a bit at LTI -> convolution using the time invariance (I don't see how the linearity could help me) but then I started doubting, proving that the LTI system -> convolution system, can I even use the fact that the convolution \$x(t)*h(t)=y(t)\$? because it seemed as if it would be using what I wanted to prove to begin with.
I feel very lost with this problem, and I would appreciate some directions.

To derive that the zero-state response for a system can be found as $y_{zs}(t) = x(t) \ast h(t)$ one assumes that the system is linear and time-invariant. Linearity ensures the superposition property, and time-invariance ensures that a delayed impulse at the input generates an equally delayed impulse response at the output. I'm not sure that there is much value to this problem.
